# Mapping and query for three way many-to-many-to-one in NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate, orm, mapping

**UPDATE:
I mistakenly pasted query code from the wrong overload. At the bottom is the fixed code**

Hi, let's say here's my domain.

I'm tracking some sport Events like say car races.

Each Race has Racers who take part in the race.

Racer is a Driver in particular Race (it has the Driver, start lane, run-time, etc).

Driver has things like Name etc... typical personal data.

I want to do the following query:
Get me all races (let's leave paging out) in this Event, showing their contestants information including data taken from the drivers.

My problem is, I don't think my mapping (or criteria query, or both) is optimal for this scenario, so I wanted to ask you, if you see any chance for optimization here.
I especially dislike the fact that currently it takes two roundtrips to the database when I think a subquery could make it work in just one go.

Here are my mapping and the query (DB is generated from the mappings)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
        assembly="Foo"
        namespace="Foo">
  <class name="Event" table="Events">
      <id name="Id">
        <generator class="guid"/>
      </id>
    <property name="EventId" not-null="true" unique="true" index="IDX_EventId" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
        assembly="Foo"
        namespace="Foo">
  <class name="Race" table="Races">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="RaceId" not-null="true" unique="true" index="IDX_RaceId"/>
    <property name="Year" not-null="true" />
    <property name="IsValid" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Time" not-null="true" />

    <many-to-one name="Event" cascade="all" not-null="true" />

    <bag name="Contestants" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" lazy="false" batch-size="20" >
      <key column="Race"/>
      <one-to-many class="Racer"/>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
        assembly="Foo"
        namespace="Foo">
  <class name="Racer" table="Racers">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid"/>      
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Race" foreign-key="FK_Racer_has_race" not-null="true" cascade="save-update" />
    <property name="Lane" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Driver" foreign-key="FK_Racer_has_driver" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
    <property name="FinishPosition" />
    <property name="Finished" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Foo"
                   namespace="Foo">
  <class name="Driver" table="Drivers">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="hilo"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" not-null="true" length="32" unique="true" index="IDX_Driver_Name" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the query code:

```
public IList<Race> GetMostRecentRacesForEvent( int eventId, int firstRaceToFetch, int count ) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For( typeof( Race ) ).
        CreateAlias( "Event", "event" ).
        Add( Restrictions.Eq( "event.EventId", eventId ) ).
        AddOrder<Race>( r => r.Time, Order.Desc ).
        SetResultTransformer( new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() ).
        SetFirstResult( firstRaceToFetch ).
        SetMaxResults( count );
    return this.ExecuteListQuery<Race>(criteria); }
```

With paging set to 3 races/page, here's the SQL it generates:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Id2_1_, RaceId2_1_, Year2_1_, IsValid2_1_, Time2_1_, Event2_1_, Id1_0_, EventId1_0_ FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY __hibernate_sort_expr_0__ DESC) as row, query.Id2_1_, query.RaceId2_1_, query.Year2_1_, query.IsValid2_1_, query.Time2_1_, query.Event2_1_, query.Id1_0_, query.EventId1_0_, query.__hibernate_sort_expr_0__ FROM (SELECT this_.Id as Id2_1_, this_.RaceId as RaceId2_1_, this_.Year as Year2_1_, this_.IsValid as IsValid2_1_, this_.Time as Time2_1_, this_.Event as Event2_1_, event1_.Id as Id1_0_, event1_.EventId as EventId1_0_, this_.Time as __hibernate_sort_expr_0__ FROM Races this_ inner join Events event1_ on this_.Event=event1_.Id WHERE event1_.EventId = @p0) query ) page WHERE page.row > 0 ORDER BY __hibernate_sort_expr_0__ DESC
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT contestant0_.Race           as Race2_,
       contestant0_.Id             as Id2_,
       contestant0_.Id             as Id0_1_,
       contestant0_.Race           as Race0_1_,
       contestant0_.Lane           as Lane0_1_,
       contestant0_.Driver         as Driver0_1_,
       contestant0_.FinishPosition as FinishPo5_0_1_,
       contestant0_.Finished       as Finished0_1_,
       driver1_.Id                 as Id3_0_,
       driver1_.Name               as Name3_0_
FROM   Racers contestant0_
       left outer join Drivers driver1_
         on contestant0_.Driver = driver1_.Id
WHERE  contestant0_.Race in ('4157280d-be8d-44be-8077-a770ef7cd394' /* @p0 */,'74e1bfaa-9926-43c7-8b17-e242634dc32f' /* @p1 */,'e1e86b67-2c37-4fbe-8793-21e84a6e4be4' /* @p2 */)
```

Comment: Why do I have the impression that there is something seriously wrong with your design, e.g., the ambiguity between Driver and Racer, and the fact that Racer is merely a list of Drivers in an specific Race. Are we using NASCAR nomenclature here (e.g. NEXTEL Cup consists of many races on many tracks) as opposed to F1/WRC? 1 event == 1 track?

Comment: Well, I didn't invent that nomenclature, I'm following my problem domain. And it's not the most relevant thing here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Stefan (to move out of the comments because this is becoming not very usable at this moment).

I redid the code according to your suggestion (without changing any mapping) and now, the query returns just one Race - the first out of three (paging is set to 3 races/page) matched by the query.

When I remove the

```
SetResultTransformer( new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() )
```

I get three items, but it's the same value three times, which is... weird. Any ideas?

Comment: It's some time ago (I'm actually about to delete my answers which didn't get any votes) The problem is, if you set FetchMode to FetchMode.Join, NH produces only one query with a join to fetch the referenced items. The root entity is returned as many times as there are children by this query. NH does not clean this up automatically. You need to tell it to do it by using the result transformer. This might be look as unnecessary. But you'll glad about this if you write some complex query where you don't want NH to add some voodoo logic.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it creates multiple queries to avoid duplicates creeping into the paging query. (but I'm not sure, I haven't seen the nhibernate internal sourcecode). Paging over a set which contains duplicates for the entity to fetch because joins were used is actually useless, so you need to be sure the resultset returned is without duplicates. I think nhibernate opts for 2 or more queries here instead of 1 query.

Comment: Interesting. Than if I changed it to Set instead of List NH will have a guarantee that there are no duplicates. I'll have to give it a try. Thanks Frans.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For( typeof( Race ), "race" )
    .CreateAlias("Event", "event")
    .CreateAlias("race.Contestants", "contestant")
    .SetFetchMode("race.Contestants", FetchMode.Join)
    .SetFetchMode("contestant.Driver", FetchMode.Join)
    .Add( Restrictions.Eq( "event.EventId", eventId ) )
    .AddOrder<Race>( r => r.Time, Order.Desc )
    .SetResultTransformer( new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() )
    .SetFirstResult( firstRaceToFetch )
    .SetMaxResults( count );
return this.ExecuteListQuery<Race>(criteria); }
```

It should make a single query and join the races, events and contestants.

You shouldn't use FetchMode.Join too much, the returning result set is larger. (It includes the race and event information as many times as you have contestants.)

Comment: Did you also join the drivers?

Comment: Stefan, sorry - I pasted code from wrong overload of my repository method. Take a look at the fixed code now.

Comment: Yeah, I implicitly join Drivers - see the mapping: <many-to-one name="Driver" foreign-key="FK_Racer_has_driver" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" fetch="join" />

Comment: @Krzysztof: I wouldn't recommend this, it always joins. In many cases it is faster with two queries instead of one, so I wouldn't put it into the mapping file. I fixed the query.

Comment: If I remove fetch="join" on Driver from the Racer mapping, and execute this code it executes separate query for each driver (N+1 warning in NHProf), and it also returns just one race, isntead of 3 as requested by SetMaxResult

Comment: The set max results is certainly applied to the joined query, so it returns 3 drivers. Don't know why it still separates the query for the driver, while it seems to join the race. Did you really set both to FetchMode.Join?

Comment: Yeah, I copy/pasted your code. It issues 2 queries. First returns 3 Races, 2nd returns Contestans info (incl data joined from Drivers table) about the first of these races.

It does select ... WHERE  contestant0_.Race = 'some-guid' /* @p0 */

Comment: To make sure - Should I change something in the mapping for that to work?

Comment: One more thing: when I remove the 
SetResultTransformer( new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer() ) it _does_ return 3 races, but it's 3 times the first race from the list returned by the 1st query. Maybe this will give you some clues...

Comment: I have to admin, I don't know this problem in this depth and had to try myself. I was quite sure that setting the fetching mode should just work. I suggest to ask your question on the nh google groups: http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers?hl=en Probably someone there knows why this doesn't work.